# Is this a wordpress bug? get_comment_link auto shoots when user visits his dashboard

Tags: comments, bug

If user is **editor**, this function auto-shoots when user visits his dashboard!

How is this possible? This function should only work when user successfully posts comment, so what is happening? could be wordpress bug?

```
function redirect_after_comment($location)
{

//This should run only when comment is confirmed. But for user level Editor, this function auto shoots!

}
add_filter('get_comment_link','redirect_after_comment');
```

1. User role is EDITOR
2. user logins, goes to dashboard.
3. Anything inside this function runs. For example return...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You mention `get_comment_link()` in the title, but reference `redirect_after_comment()` in the question body. Also: can you provide a bit more detail about what actually happens?

Comment: Could be one of the dashboards widgets("recent comments" maybe?). try `if(is_admin()) return;` as first line of function

Comment: @ChipBennett redirect_after_comment is just my function name, isn't it?

Comment: @MridulAggarwal
Impossible that it is widget, because this doesn't happen with admin.

Comment: @MridulAggarwal I outlined details.

Comment: Okay, I misread your question originally. I see that you're hooking into the `get_comment_link` filter (*and that's probably your issue*).

Comment: @ChipBennett exactly. I'm trying to understand if this is wordpress bug, doesn't seem to be a known issue. Happens only with the user role = Editor.

Comment: Without knowing the content of your callback, it is impossible to determine why the callback is executing for Editor-role users, but not for Admin-role users. Regardless, I think the underlying issue is that you're hooking into the wrong hook. See answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're intending to redirect the user to a certain page, after the user posts a comment?

If so: **why are you hooking into `get_commenet_link`** for this redirect? The [`get_comment_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_link) function is intended to return the permalink to a given comment. The **`get_comment_link`** filter is intended to filer the comment permalink returned by `get_comment_link()`. By hooking into `get_comment_link`, your callback is going to fire *everywhere* that `get_comment_link()` is called. Here is the filter [inside of the function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L472):

```
return apply_filters( 'get_comment_link', $link . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID, $comment, $args );
```

I would recommend using [a more appropriate hook related to the comment-posting process](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Comment.2C_Ping.2C_and_Trackback_Actions), such as **`comment_post`**.

Comment: It still makes no sense to me, but comment_post hook seems better :)

Comment: What still makes no sense? We'll try to help make things more clear. :)

Comment: Well, the fact that get_comment_link runs when user Editor logs into dashboard seems a bit odd. Btw, I use that function to hook into url redirect after comment, so user is redirected to correct language website after submission. Unfortunately qtranslate doesn't do it out of the box. So I divided my function into two parts, 1 part which was breaking dashboard went into comment_post and url manipulation I left in get_comment_link and it seems to work now. ty.

Comment: I assume that `get_comment_link` filters get applied when the dashboard is rendered because *comment links* are being displayed on the dashboard, somewhere. But I'm still curious *why you chose that particular filter*, since the `get_comment_link()` template tag has *nothing to do* with the comment-posting process/execution.